Netsuite: search for customers with address field "override" ticked
Im not sure this is possible, as its not in the api or selectable options for customer record when creating a saved search.


Ok so its not possible via a customer record, but I just found another way. It is available via a transaction search, and if a customer has override enabled in their address, that will flow through to any sales orders made by default.
So you can make a saved search showing and filtering by the shipping field -> override
And then optionally (as shown below) group the results by customer name and sort by recent.
And then work through the list and manually editing the customers in the results.



In terms of API you can also do this in SuiteQL. The results could be returned as from the getInput phase of a map/reduce; dumped to the console and put into a spreadsheet; reported as a customer link in a SuiteLet etc.
e.g.
require(['N/query'], query => {


    const sqlStr = `
    select count(cust.entityid) as custs, count(cab.internalid) as addresses

/*, cab.label */
 from customer cust, customeraddressbook cab, customerAddressbookEntityAddress ea
where cab.entity = cust.id and cab.addressbookaddress = ea.nkey and ea.override = 'T'
`;

    console.log(sqlStr);

    console.log(query.runSuiteQL({
        query: sqlStr
    }).asMappedResults().map((r, idx)=>{
        // if(!idx) 
        console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
        return `${r.entity}\t${r.entityid}\t${r.tranid}\t${r.applied}`;
    }).join('\n'));
    console.log('done');

});

    

